# React Router 4: either-or routes

Tags: react-router

I have a case where I want to set up an url-scheme on the form

```
/items/ <- list of items
/items/1 <- item1
/items/2 <- item2
...
/items/2 <- itemn
/items/new <- create item
```

From my expirience with other routing frameworks, I've tried this:

```
function (props) {
    var match = props.match;
    return (
        <div>
            <Route path={ `${match.url}/new` }
                   component={ Create } />
            <Route path={ `${match.url}/:id` }
                   component={ Details } />
            <Route exact
                   path={ match.url }
                   component={ List } />
        </div>
    );
}
```

However, when i navigate to /items/new, both the Create-component and the Detail Component renders.

My workaround is to wrap the Details-component like this:

```
function DetailContainer (props) {
    if (props.match.params.id === 'new') {
      return null;
    }
    return (
      <Detail {...props} />
    );
}
```

But this seems a bit hackish to me. Is it possible to set up this kind of behaviour using only routes? I know this is how stuff is done in Flask, but from what I gather from the rr4 documentation the concept of routes here is a bit different (meaning that several routes can render at once).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

On Twitter I was pointed in the direction of https://reacttraining.com/react-router/web/example/ambiguous-matches

Switch was what I was looking for:

```
function (props) {
    var match = props.match;
    return (
        <div>
            <Switch>
                <Route path={ `${match.url}/new` }
                       component={ Create } />
                <Route path={ `${match.url}/:id` }
                       component={ Details } />
            </Switch>
            <Route exact
                   path={ match.url }
                   component={ List } />
        </div>
    );
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The path-part of the router seems to be based on this module: https://www.npmjs.com/package/path-to-regexp

Since it looks like you can use regex-expressions inside the path part could you not use

```
path={ `${match.url}/(:id?!new)` }
```

or something.. (My regex fu is not awesome at this point)

Comment: Yeah, this could probably work, although I think using Switch is cleaner (well: all code that avoids regex is cleaner imho)